# Google API refresh token returns false

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, google-oauth

I have the following function that I'm using to refresh a token using the Google OAuth API.

```
private void RefreshExpiredToken(UserCredential credential)
{
  if (!credential.Token.IsExpired(SystemClock.Default)) 
    return;

  var success = credential.RefreshTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None).Result;
  if (success)
    Log.Info($"RefreshTokenAsync successful UserId=[{credential.UserId}]");
  else
    Log.Error($"RefreshTokenAsync failed UserId=[{credential.UserId}]");
}
```

I've stripped out the error handling in this post to simplify the example. Essentially, this is intended to evaluate whether or not the token is expired and if not, will refresh the token. The problem I'm having is that sometimes, the RefreshTokenAsync code returns false and I don't understand why that's happening.

The credential flow is using GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer, but I don't think that's relevant to the problem.

When I look at the source code for the RefreshTokenAsync function, it reads as follows:

```
/// <summary>
/// Refreshes the token by calling to
/// <see cref="M:Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows.IAuthorizationCodeFlow.RefreshTokenAsync(System.String,System.String,System.Threading.CancellationToken)" />.
/// Then it updates the <see cref="T:Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse" /> with the new token instance.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="taskCancellationToken">Cancellation token to cancel an operation.</param>
/// <returns><c>true</c> if the token was refreshed.</returns>
public async Task<bool> RefreshTokenAsync(CancellationToken taskCancellationToken)
{
  if (this.Token.RefreshToken == null)
  {
    UserCredential.Logger.Warning("Refresh token is null, can't refresh the token!");
    return false;
  }
  TokenResponse tokenResponse = await this.flow.RefreshTokenAsync(this.userId, this.Token.RefreshToken, taskCancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
  UserCredential.Logger.Info("Access token was refreshed successfully");
  if (tokenResponse.RefreshToken == null)
    tokenResponse.RefreshToken = this.Token.RefreshToken;
  this.Token = tokenResponse;
  return true;
}
```

From the looks of it, the only time this should return false to the *success* variable as the Result is if the RefreshToken is null. I've verified that this is not the case, so I don't understand what's happening.

The only working theories I have are:

1. The async code is being called incorrectly from the non-async code. That said, this is exactly how many of the examples for how to use this library are set up.
2. There's so much happening on the server that the underlying HttpClient request (which is buried under several layers of async calls) is either running into some sort of network problem where it's unable to complete the request due to a lack of available network resources and this ends up being surfaced as an inability to refresh the token.

But from the RefreshTokenAsync code, I'm really just not sure how that can happen, outside of something to do with the .ConfigureAwait(false) function, which is used pervasively through the call stack.

Immediately after this code is called, we're logging into the Google Workspace mailboxes and are able to access them, so in some ways, it feels like this is a red herring error message/result.

These error messages end up in the logs a LOT, so I'd like to resolve this if at all possible. It doesn't seem like it's safe to ignore this problem though to be honest, the connections still seem to be working for the most part. It's just not clear why the result is a failure sometimes and not others.

Anyone have any ideas as to what might be going on?

---

**Update:**
I updated the call to RefreshTokenAsync from:

```
var success = credential.RefreshTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None).Result;
```

to

```
var success = Task.Run(async() => await credential.RefreshTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None)).Result;
```

And after running it overnight on the development systems, this seems to be working properly. I'm no longer seeing any of the failures that I was seeing before.

I thought these would be functionally equivalent, but based on the behavior, it appears that they are not. I think I'm not understanding something about how this call to an async function from a non-async function works. Can someone explain what's different or is this "fix" just a coincidence?

---

Minimal reproducible example below. Make sure to set the ClientId and ClientSecret. It should work as-is otherwise and I left comments in for the code that doesn't appear to be working properly and the code that does within the RefreshExpiredToken function.

```
public class GoogleOAuth2Config
{
    private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
    private readonly IDataStore _dataStore;

    // scope definition for accessing Gmail and getting email info
    private readonly IEnumerable<string> _scopes = new[]
    {
            "openid",   // Authenticate using OpenID Connect
            "profile",  // View your basic profile info
            "email",    // View your email address
            "https://mail.google.com"   // Full access to manage your email. Also provides IMAP and SMTP access.
        };

    /// <summary>
    /// Default Constructor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dataStore"></param>
    public GoogleOAuth2Config(IDataStore dataStore)
    {
        _dataStore = dataStore;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Obtains Google's OAuth 2.0 access token identified by specified local ID.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="localStorageId">A local ID, which identifies an access token in local storage.
    ///     If the token is found in the local storage, the user is not redirected to Google's login page.
    ///     Local ID can be any string e.g. username.</param>
    /// <param name="username"></param>
    /// <returns>The Google's OAuth 2.0 access token.</returns>
    public string GetImapAccessToken(string localStorageId, string username)
    {
        // First, load the TokenResponse
        var tokenResponse = _dataStore.GetAsync<TokenResponse>(localStorageId).Result;

        // Set up the ClientSecrets for the authorization flow
        var clientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
        {
            ClientId = "TODO:GoogleClientId",
            clientSecrets = "TODO:GoogleClientSecret"
        };

        // Build Google's UserCredential object
        IAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(
            new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
            {
                ClientSecrets = clientSecrets,
                Scopes = _scopes,
                DataStore = _dataStore
            });
        var credential = new UserCredential(flow, localStorageId, tokenResponse);

        // refresh token if necessary, then return the resulting AccessToken
        RefreshExpiredToken(credential, false);
        return credential.Token.AccessToken;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Refreshes the Google's OAuth 2.0 token.
    /// NOTE: This automatically saves the TokenResponse back to the database
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="credential">User credential holding the token.</param>
    /// <param name="force">True to force refreshing; false to refresh only if token is expired.</param>
    /// <param name="sourceDescriptor"></param>
    /// <param name="username"></param>
    private void RefreshExpiredToken(UserCredential credential, bool force)
    {
        // check whether to refresh the token
        if (!force && !credential.Token.IsExpired(SystemClock.Default))
            return;

        var originalRefreshToken = credential.Token.RefreshToken;
        
        // The following line returns false quite often
        // var success = credential.RefreshTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None).Result;
        
        // This line seems to work fine and has returned true for the last 12+ hours
        var success = Task.Run(async() => await credential.RefreshTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None)).Result;
        if (success)
            Log.Info($"RefreshTokenAsync succeeded. UserId=[{credential.UserId}]");
        else
        {
            Log.Error(originalRefreshToken == null
                ? $"RefreshTokenAsync failed. UserId=[{credential.UserId}]. Original RefreshToken=[NULL]"
                : $"RefreshTokenAsync failed. UserId=[{credential.UserId}]. Original RefreshToken=[{originalRefreshToken}]");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Mike. I can see that `UserCredential` has a `Token` property with a [public setter](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/e369d9501784991154857c2dc56d7d92c48e4511/Src/Support/Google.Apis.Auth/OAuth2/UserCredential.cs#L43). Are you sure this is not being manipulated outside of the code you are providing here?

Comment: Also, because you are doing sync over async anyway, you could wrap the call to `credential.RefreshTokenAsync` in a `lock` statement to see if the strange behavior is due to some [underlying racing condition](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/e369d9501784991154857c2dc56d7d92c48e4511/Src/Support/Google.Apis.Auth/OAuth2/UserCredential.cs#L177).

Comment: @yv989c Yes, that Token property is not being manipulated outside of this code. I had noticed the comment in the code regarding concurrent calls, but it didn't say how that might happen. I have two separate processes, potentially on different machines, both of which could call this using DI, but those are definitely different objects. Pretty sure there's not a race condition, based on how the code is structured. But assuming there was, if one refreshes the token, how would the other "fail" and return false? I just don't see that potential code path and logged Token.RefreshToken to be certain.

Comment: Forgot to comment on your lock proposition. I implemented a Redlock locking mechanism to give me a distributed lock that would work across multiple processes so only one will ever work on this at at a time for a given token. It didn't seem to have any effect, but the code update using Task.Run appeared to change the behavior. So still struggling to understand exactly what's happening or if it's something to worry about.

Comment: I've pinged a colleague who knows more than me to look into this... but do you really need to be manually refreshing anyway? `UserCredential` will refresh the token automatically (and do so in the background slightly *before* it expires, assuming there's a request made in that time) so we don't normally expect calling code to manually refresh it at all. I don't understand why it would return false though...

Comment: As @JonSkeet said, you don't need to refresh the token yourself, when you use this credential to make requests to Google Services, the token will be refreshed automatically.

Comment: The second thing I would look at is where the UserCredential that you are receiving is coming from? Does it actually have a refresh token?
You've also said that you have stripped error handling and also said that after using Task.Run you are not seeing the same failures as you did before. What where those failures? Did you, for instance, see IO errors around a file being used? Any HTTP errors?

Comment: The RefreshToken is retrieved from a database via the IDataStore. I'm 100% certain it exists and is valid. As for whether it needs to be refreshed manually? I could call GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync and return that instead of attempting to manually refresh followed by returning credential.Token.AccessToken. I may make that change, but it still doesn't explain why this is returning false. Even without knowing anything else about how it's supposed to be used, I can't see how it returns false. Seems like some sort of obscure problem with Task.Result

Comment: If you can provide a [mcve], we'd be very happy to look into it more. But how are you using the credential - why are you accessing the AccessToken directly at all? You say you're accessing the Google Workspace mailboxes - are you not doing that using the client libraries which support UserCredential directly? I would try to avoid low-level work with the credentials if possible.

Comment: I retrieve the access token directly because I need to pass it into a .NET library called Rebex Secure Mail that does the underlying work of interacting with the mailbox and this is part of the authentication needed to create the authentication that's used by the Rebex ImapClient. I've done what I can to provide a minimal reproducible example as a self-contained class. FYI: This uses v1.32.1 of the library. Newest version is 1.60.0, so I probably need to update it but maybe there's an underlying problem there that's since been fixed?

Comment: It's not clear from your example what is the underlying type of the data store and that may be key here.

Comment: Also, there are quite a few steps that you could skip by using some of the built-in library functionality. Basically, you are doing some of what Google.Apis.Auth library is doing, but possibly not all. If you share the type of the data store, include the using statements of your code, include a project file so we know the correct versions of all your dependencies, and also, please clarify whether this runs within a continuous process, for how long or how often, etc., then we might be able to reproduce.

Comment: But please do update to Google.Apis.Auth 1.60.0, the version you are using is over 5 years old, there's really no telling what may be wrong there at this point.

Comment: The IDataStore is a simple repository that stores the Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse object. It's converted to Json and encrypted using an external Azure KeyVault that stores the encryption keys. I don't think this is relevant because as I pointed out, the code that's commented out in RefreshExpiredToken is returning false, while the updated code seems to work fine. This code hasn't been touched in 5+ years and with the exception of the logging messages that this returns false, it otherwise seems to work fine. It was just a question about why it would return false.